# How to create a Spring authentication filter with pattern /**

Tags: authentication, spring-security, servlet-filters

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" pattern="/**" 
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
</sec:http>

HI,
```

What I'm trying to do seems like it would be so simple, yet i've been trying to figure out how to do it for hours. Hopefully someone can help.

I simply want to create an authentication filter that will intercept all incoming requests, do some processing, then pass it on to the next filter in the chain.

When I try and do that using a pttern of /**, I keep getting that error "A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration" even though i've tried all kinds of things, like guaranteeing my filter is the very last one listed in the security.xml file. I've even attempted to specify the order with a filterChainProxy definition like this:

```
<beans:bean id="filterChainProxy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map>
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="<filterlist, with mine being the very last!>" />
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>
```

Nothing seemed to work, despite spending hours researching and googling to try and figure that out, so I gave up, and created an entry in the web.xml file for my filter. Finally, I hit a breakpoint in the filter, so I knew it was getting invoked. But then the problem I ran into was, nothing was getting injected by Spring, I'm assuming because I went "outside the framework", and, I can't even pull the authenticated user, I get a Spring error saying i'm not authenticated, yet other filters defined inside the security.xml can pull it just fine.

I'm not sure what to do here; very suprised something so simply is so difficult.

Please advise, thanks

Comment: The error message you are getting is most likely because you have more than one `http` element in your configuration and you've defined this one before the others. But it's hard to say from the information in your question. You'd be better posting the actual configuration.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned in the original post that I've made sure this is the very last http definition in the file, and there is only one file with http definitions.

Comment: I even removed all other filter patterns from the configuration... same thing

Comment: Do I HAVE to definte a pattern, or can I simply define the filter? I tried just defining a filter, without specifying an http pattern for it, and I never hit a breakpoint, like the filter didn't get picked up. I'm trying to do authorization against a cookie in this filter... I simply want to add a filter and have it get executed.